# How to choose most likely/famous place_id candidates when multiple place_ids are returned by places API

Tags: google-places-api

Let's use a very famous location as an example, Trafalgar Square. When I send this query

gmap = googlemaps.Client(key)
gmap.find_place(input = "Trafalgar Square, London", input_type = "textquery")

It returns 2 place_id candidates
ChIJH-tBOc4EdkgRJ8aJ8P1CUxo
ChIJ1dgZPM4EdkgRGwKiy-jluTE

If you try that out on maps.google.com web page, same thing. I mean, for some place so popular, I wouldn't expect to have to deal with ambiguity. What is a good way for me to, without prompting my user, to choose the more likely candidate? In my use case, I need to find the more "famous" one. Before you say "just pick the first one", I want to point out another example:

gmap.find_place(input = "Hanseatic Museum, Burgen", input_type = "textquery")

which also returns 2 place_id candidates
ChIJWXsIuAH8PEYRyCgqwQVId3g
ChIJ_42Xv6f-PEYRDMlEjejgxAg

This time, if you punch in the name in maps.google.com, the second one is an exact name match (Hanseatic Museum), while the first one points to a location of a slightly different name (Schøtstuene, Hanseatic Assembly Rooms). This leads me to believe the candidate list is not ordered by accuracy/guess.

Any suggestion?

Tried
gmap.find_place(input = "Trafalgar Square, London", input_type = "textquery")

Expected *one* return place_id, instead, got 2, which point the same place

Tried
gmap.find_place(input = "Hanseatic Museum, Burgen", input_type = "textquery")

Expected *one* return place_id, because only one of them matches exactly, or at least expect the one that matches exactly to be the first in the list

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your concern. Now with regards to your question, are you by any means using the python library `googlemaps` in your implementation?